# File written through FileOutputStream in Java is not being accessed by python using AudioSegment.from_file

Tags: java, python

I am writing one file using Java as following.

```
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\MyFile.mp4");
    File f = new File(path.toString());
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
    IOUtils.copy(stream, fout);
    fout.close();
```

And consuming file in Python as following.

```
my_file = Path("C:\\Temp\\MyFile.mp4")
song = AudioSegment.from_file(my_file)
```

And it gives me following error.

```
'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

What wrong am I doing? It seems something is holding file from java side and because of that I am not able to access it in python. or May be something I am doing wrong in python itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

Actually I was using video file for AudioSegment in python "mp4" and that was giving this error somehow.

With wav file it is working fine.